# How to block the generation of superclass with .__new__, while allowing the generation of its subclass?

Tags: python

I have an class 'A', which has subclasses 'B', 'C', and D.
'A' serves only the purpose of categorization and inheritance, so I don't want user to create the instance of 'A'.
However, I want to create the instances of 'B', 'C', and 'D' as usual.

First, I blocked the generation of the instance of 'A' by overriding `A.__new__`.
Then, I overrode `B.__new__` again, just like below.

```py
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        raise AssertionError('A cannot be generated directly.')

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(cls,B).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

However, with this code, generation of B returns same AssertionError.
I understand that since `A.__new__` is disabled, `super(cls,B).__new__` (which is exactly same as `A.__new__`) is disabled as well.
Is there any way to generate the instance of subclass, without invoking the `__new__` of its superclass?

#### Edited - Resolved

Instead of invoking `A.__new__`, I invoked the `__new__` method of higher superclass (which is 'object'). This solution circumvented the problem.

The new code is something like this:

```py
class A(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        raise AssertionError('A cannot be generated directly.')

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

Note that it is `return object.__new__(cls)`, not `return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)`. This is because `object.__new__` doesn't have any argument except `cls`, therefore no arguments must be passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly invoking `A.__new__` in the `B.__new__` method. This version works fine:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        raise AssertionError()

class B(A):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
       pass
```

Result:

```
>>> x = A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __new__
AssertionError
>>> y = B()
>>> y
>>>
```

Note that `B.__new__` is now pretty much useless: I don't actually get a `B` instance (`y` is empty). I'm assuming you have an actual reason to be modifying `__new__`, in which case you'd put your replacement code where I have `pass`.

If you *don't* have a good reason to modify `__new__`, *don't*. You almost always want `__init__` instead.

```
>>> class A1:
...     def __init__(self):
...             raise ValueError()
... 
>>> class B1(A1):
...     def __init__(self):
...             pass
... 
>>> A1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in __init__
ValueError
>>> B1()
<__main__.B1 object at 0x7fa97b3f26d8>
```

Note how I get an actual default-constructed `B1` object now.

As a general rule, you'll only want to modify `__new__` if you're working with immutable types (like `str` and `tuple`) or building new metaclasses. You can see more details on what each method is responsible for [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But now I'm just being curious - would there be any way to generate the instance of B, without referring to A?

Comment: @JSS You mean in the first code I posted? Sure, implement a proper `__new__` method instead of just using `pass`. In the second code, you don't have to bother writing your own `__new__` and can let Python handle that part for you.

Comment: Point to info that describes the responsibility of each (new and init).

Comment: @Pynchia Good call; added